# Accessing aliases in Cypress with "this"

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to share values between my `before` and `beforeEach` hooks using aliases. It currently works if my value is a string but when the value is an object, the alias is only defined in the first test, every test after that `this.user` is undefined in my `beforeEach` hook. How can I share a value which is an object between tests?

This is my code:

```js
before(function() {
  const email = `test+${uuidv4()}@example.com`;
  cy
    .register(email)
    .its("body.data.user")
    .as("user");
});

beforeEach(function() {
  console.log("this.user", this.user); // This is undefined in every test except the first
});
```

Comment: This doesn't sound right (nor the answer by @RichardMatsen). Can you post an example where exactly the `this.user` is undefined in subsequent tests?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The alias is ***undefined in every test except the first*** because aliases are cleared down **after** each test.

Aliased variables are accessed via `cy.get('@user')` syntax. Some commands are inherently asynchronous, so using a wrapper to access the variable ensures it is resolved before being used.

See documentation [Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#) and [get](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Syntax).

---

There does not seem to be a way to explicitly preserve an alias, as the is with [cookies](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies)

```
Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce(names...)
```

but this [recipe for preserving fixtures](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/db2f5a9c2e3dcf3b4f2b352f10a2d6ed443946fe/examples/fundamentals__fixtures/cypress/integration/load-fixtures-spec.js#L103) shows a way to preserve global variables by reinstating them in a `beforeEach()`

```js
let city
let country

before(() => {
  // load fixtures just once, need to store in
  // closure variables because Mocha context is cleared
  // before each test
  cy.fixture('city').then((c) => {
    city = c
  })

  cy.fixture('country').then((c) => {
    country = c
  })
})

beforeEach(() => {
  // we can put data back into the empty Mocha context before each test
  // by the time this callback executes, "before" hook has finished
  cy.wrap(city).as('city')
  cy.wrap(country).as('country')
})
```

---

If you want to access a global `user` value, you might try something like

```js
let user;

before(function() {
  const email = `test+${uuidv4()}@example.com`;
  cy
    .register(email)
    .its("body.data.user")
    .then(result => user = result);
});

beforeEach(function() {
  console.log("global user", user); 
  cy.wrap(user).as('user');              // set as alias
});

it('first', () => {
  cy.get('@user').then(val => {
    console.log('first', val)            // user alias is valid
  })
})

it('second', () => {
  cy.get('@user').then(val => {
    console.log('second', val)           // user alias is valid
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with the `cy.get('@user')` in the end. However, the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Sharing-Context) implies that the `this.user` syntax should work in the way that I tried.

Comment: You are quite right, I recall seeing that doc page. Perhaps there's a delay caused by the `.register()` command (is it a custom command?)

Comment: Yes `.register()` is a custom command, it calls `cy.request()`. I just find it odd that the alias is always only available in the beforeEach of first test, any tests after the first it's undefined. It seems like Cypress clears aliases between tests.

Comment: I did a little experimenting on one of my tests and found that the alias is indeed cleared in the second call to `beforeEach()`. Maybe all alias's are cleared to ensure that values from one test don't bleed over into another.

Comment: BTW, I couldn't get the alias value on the `this` scope (using Cypress.io v1.4.2). Perhaps your custom command is putting it there? If so, my sample code which uses the global variable should reference it in the console.log without `this` context.

Comment: This is exactly what Cypress recomends NOT doing. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases

Comment: @itcropper, the problem still exists. The documents do not cover the scenario where alias is created in a `before()` as opposed to `beforeEach()`, so this is a valid usage.

Comment: This answer is not correct. See my answer below.

Comment: "Typically in Cypress you hardly need to ever use const, let, or var"  https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Variables

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
console.log("global user", this.user);
```

with

```
cy.log(this.user);
```

and it should work as expected.

The reason for this is the asynchronous nature of cypress commands. Think of it as a two-step process: All the cypress commands are not doing what you think, when they run. They just build up a chain of commands. This chain is executed as the test later on.

This is obviously not the case for other commands like `console.log()`. This command is executed when preparing the test.

This is [explained in great detail in the cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Asynchronous):

But I felt it very hard to get my head around this. You have to get used to it.
One rule of thumb: Almost every command in your test should be a cypress command.

So just use `cy.log` instead of `console.log`

If you must use console.log you can do it like this:

```
cy.visit("/).then(() => console.log(this.user))
```

this way the `console.log` is chained. Or if you do not have a subject to chain off, build your own custom command like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("console", (message) => console.log(message))
cy.console(this.user)
```

Another mistake with using `this` in cypress is using arrow functions. If you do, you don't have access to the `this` you are expecting. See [Avoiding the use of this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Avoiding-the-use-of-this) in the cypress docs.

Comment: Nope, that's misleading. `cy.log()` logs to the Cypress log whereas `console.log()` logs to dev-tools. Other than that, they both output the variable.

Comment: I don't think it is misleading as the key to the problem is the command chain. But I added a paragraph explaining how to use console.log if this is what the question is all about

Comment: Just try it, you will see it's just not true.

Comment: See [The order of hook and test execution](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#The-order-of-hook-and-test-execution-is-as-follows).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: If you want an aliased `user` object available in each of your tests, you must define it in a `beforeEach` hook not a `before` hook.

Cypress performs a lot of cleanup between tests and this includes clearing all aliases. According to the Sharing Contexts section of [Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Sharing-Context): "Aliases and properties are automatically cleaned up after each test." The result you are seeing (your alias is cleaned after the first test and subsequently undefined) is thus expected behavior.

I cannot determine what `register` does in the original post, but it seems your intention is to save the overhead of performing API calls repeatedly in a `beforeEach` hook. It is definitely easiest to put everything you want in the `beforeEach` hook and ignore the overhead (also, pure API calls with no UI interaction will not incur much penalty).

If you really need to avoid repetition, this should not be accomplished through regular variables due to potential timing problems with Cypress' custom chainables. This is an [anti-pattern they publish](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases). The best way to do this would be:

- Create a [fixture file](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Fixture-Files) with static user data that you will use to conduct the test. (Remove the uuidv4.)
- For the set of tests that need your user data, call `register` in a `before` hook using the fixture data. This will create the data in the system under test.
- Use a `beforeEach` hook to load the fixture data and alias it for each of your tests. Now, the static data you need is accessible with no API calls and it is guaranteed to be in the system properly thanks to the `before` hook.
- Run your tests using the alias.
- Clean up the data in an `after` hook (since your user no longer has a random email, you need to add this step).

If you need to do the above for the whole test suite, put your `before` and `after` hooks in the [support file](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Support-file) to make them global.