# Grab a string to use in a .visit() call in cypress

Tags: testing, cypress

I have a dom element that contains the string or a url that I would like to visit. I have labelled the dom element with a data attribute for easy reference.

[image]

Above where it says 'Create Topic' in bold is the string and in the console, you can see it has a `data-test='topicUrl` attribute.

I want to capture this string value so that I can visit the url a a later point.

I followed [the docs on Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#) and tried

```
cy.get('[data-test="topicUrl"]').invoke('text').as('Url')
```

so that I could visit the page by using

```
cy.visit(this.Url)
```

But that doesn't work, it errors out with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Url' of undefined` in the console.

How do I grab the text in a DOM element so that I can use it to visit a url at a later point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable as a parameter in an API call in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58757793/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-parameter-in-an-api-call-in-cypress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache it to a variable and issue the `cy.visit` in a callback to ensure the variable is populated:

```
let url;
cy.get('[data-test="topicUrl"]').invoke('text')
    .then( value => {
        url = value;
    });

cy.then(() => {

    return cy.visit(url);
});
```

Using `cy.then()` directly (instead of chaining it off of another command) isn't documented and might be removed in the future when `cy.resolve( promise )` is implemented.

Maybe it's better to use `cy.wrap().then(() => {})` which should work forever (?).

(going entirely from memory, so lemme know if it's not working and I'll update when I get a chance to run it.)

Answer (score 3):

See this question [using-aliases-in-cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431483/using-aliases-in-cypress) of a few days ago, I don't think the `this.Url` syntax works universally. The docs you referenced refer to 'mochas shared context object' and 'aliases are automatically cleaned up between tests'.

This leads me to think that you can ***only use `this.Url` when the alias is set in a beforeEach()***

You could try the following

```js
cy.get('[data-test="topicUrl"]').invoke('text').as('Url')
...
cy.get('@Url').then(url => cy.visit(url))
```

Although, this feels more like a click than a visit as the url looks relative to the current site.

```js
cy.get('[data-test="topicUrl"]').click()
cy.wait(100)  // a wait might be needed
```

or from line 847 of the cypress example_spec.js,

```js
cy.get('[data-test="topicUrl"]').as('Url')
...
cy.get('@Url').click()
```