# Cypress access alias with this.* doesn't works

Tags: testing, automated-tests, this, cypress, arrow-functions

I'm having a little problem understanding Cypress documentation. In the [alias section](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Accessing-Fixtures) they've added a use case of accessing alias with fixtures using the `this.*` reference:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    // alias the users fixtures
    cy.fixture("users.json").as("users");
});

it("utilize users in some way", function () {
    // access the users property
    const user = this.users[0];

    // make sure the header contains the first
    // user's name
    cy.get("header").should("contain", user.name);
});
```

But when I try to reproduce it, I keep getting the error: `Cannot read property 'SOAP_body' of undefined`.

I don't understand where is my error. Here is my spec:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress"/>

describe("SOAP API Test", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.fixture("SOAP_body.xml").as("SOAP_body");
    });

    it("Test with task", function () {
        const body = this.SOAP_body;

        cy.request({

            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "content-type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                Authorization: "Token myVerySecretToken",
                SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/TrackingFull",
            },
            url: `https://path.of/the/application.asmx`,
            body: body,
            failOnStatusCode: false,

        }).then((result) => {

            expect(result.status).to.equal(200);
            cy.task("XMLtoJSON", result.body).then((response) => {
                expect(
                    response.elements[0].elements[1].elements[0].elements[0]
                        .elements[1].elements[0].elements[0].elements[0]
                        .elements[0].elements[0].text
                ).to.equal("something");
                
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and my task

```js
/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */

module.exports = (on, config) => {

    on("task", {
        XMLtoJSON(XML_body) {
            var convert = require("xml-js");
            let result = convert.xml2js(XML_body, {
                compact: false,
                spaces: 2,
            });
            return result;
        },
    });
};
```

Using `debugger` just before the const definition I can see that the variables are undefined[image: debbuger output]

I do know about `cy.get()`, but I just wanted to learn how to use the `this.*` pattern.

Comment: I know about the existence of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431483/accessing-aliases-in-cypress-with-this?rq=1), but unfortunately, they succumbed to `cy.get()` usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After fiddling with the code I've realized that I was using an `arrow function` in the step definition:

`it("Test with task", () => { ... }`

I've done it simply because I use a lot of code snippets in VSC, and never paid attention to the syntax is used.

So, after seeing it, I've remembered that it would never work, as the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) says:

> An arrow function expression is a compact alternative to a traditional
> function expression, but is limited and can't be used in all
> situations.
>
> Differences & Limitations:
>
> - Does not have its own bindings to **`this`** [image: Facepalm] or `super`, and should not be used as `methods`.
> - Does not have `arguments`, or `new.target` keywords.
> - Not suitable for `call`, `apply` and `bind` methods, which generally rely on establishing a `scope`.
> - Can not be used as `constructors`.
> - Can not use `yield`, within its body.

The solution was simple as replacing it with a function definition:

`it("Test with task", function () { ... }`

and the `this` context was as expected

[image: debbuger output]

Moral of the history, don't trust blindly in your code editor (even if its VSC)

Comment: it gets even worse for me because they [documented it](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Avoiding-the-use-of-this) in the cypress site...

Comment: I also missed the documentation... thank you so much for pointing this out!